# Ошибка базы данных mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ошибка базы данных MySQL

```
 General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('mysqladmin'@'%') does not exist
```

Не понимаю почему она возникла и как от нее избавиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов решения может быть несколько. Один из них, выполнить следующую команду:

```
grant all on *.* to 'mysqladmin'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Также множество предложений по решению проблемы можно найти по след. ссылкам:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql

http://michael-xiii.blogspot.ru/2012/01/mysqldump-got-error-1449-user-specified.html (здесь на русском)